Xcode 16 hangs when trying to install an iOS App
I've recently updated to Xcode 16 and since then I have been unable to build any of my apps for iOS. Prior to the update, everything was working fine, but now I run on a device and I get an infinite spinner that says: "Installing AppName to DeviceName and on the device it shows as 1/3 installed with the word Loading...
What's shown in Xcode:

What's shown on the device:

I have tried a couple of workarounds: like unpairing my device and then repairing, restarting Xcode and phone, terminating CoreDeviceService from activity manager, uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode, and cleaning the build folder, but at best I can run successfully once or maybe twice before the issue occurs again or it does nothing and wastes time. I would try installing an older version of Xcode but the only version that my Mac supports is 16 because I run Sequoia. I need help finding a permanent solution to this because Xcode 16 is just flat-out unusable at the moment. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I am running on a 2020 MacBook pro, running an Intel chip, running macOS Sequoia 15.0.1. The device I am trying to install an app to is an iPhone 13 running iOS 18.0.1.
Thanks for any help.

I'm having the same problem, sometimes it gets stuck in attaching also. I restart both my Mac book and phone and such and sometimes it works but many times it doesn't, this bug is wasting my time.

This seems to be fixed with Sequoia 15.1

Two issues plagues recent Xcode versions. One is that Xcode will try to provision when it's not necessary, see https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/756120 and the other is that Xcode will always try to deploy via. WiFi rather than your cable. This can be worked around by enabling Airplane mode on your phone when deploying.

Please update the question to clarify which statement is correct: "I've recently updated to Xcode 16" and "I would try installing an older version of Xcode but the only version that my Mac supports is 16 because I run Sequoia" appear to be mutually exclusive claims.

Late response but I was able to solve this by deleting a run script I had added. It was to do with Firebase crashlytics. Once the script was removed I could install again. I also updated xCode and any other hangs were solved.

this issue has been addressed in macos 15.1 (24B83).

I have seen this before, but not with Xcode 16
What worked for me was to clear Xcode cache and indexes.
System Preferences > Storage > Developer


Remove the Derivated Data of the project.
If the problem persist, just close(not kill) the proccess CoreDeviceService:


Apart from the recommendations above, I would also suggest checking for any apps or services that might be filtering or blocking connections on both your iPhone and Mac. In some cases, simply deactivating these apps may not be enough; you might need to uninstall them. In my experience, I had to uninstall the apps to resolve the issue.

I have faced the same issue since the macOS 15 upgrade. The best workaround that at least lets me achieve consistent builds is as follows:

Locate the folder with the .ipa file by revealing the Products -> Your app in finder
Remove the .ipa file in that folder (just one file)
Start the build.
Repeat the step 2 EVERY TIME before staring the build

Note: in case the build system is blocked, kill the CoreDeviceService process and try again.

Had the same issue (on osx 15.0.1, Xcode 16/16.1RC, iOS 18.0.1). I upgraded to osx 15.1 yesterday and the issue seems to be solved now.
